# Icinga agentless configuration

Tags: performance, monitoring, icinga2

We are planning to use icinga2 to monitor servers and performance data. But we can't install any agents on the remote hosts ( to be monitored). I believe there is agentless monitoring in Icinga2 but couldn't locate any relevant documents.  I need document regarding what kind of data can be collected using icing2 agentless monitoring.

BTW, any other tool which can do similar job ( agent less monitoring)
Please advise.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The documentation provides a chapter on more or less agent-based/less monitoring and should give you some starting points. Whether to use SSH, SNMP, etc. - it really depends on your network and check/metric requirements. Specify what exactly you need from checks, and look for specific plugins and transports then.

https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/agent-based-checks-addon

If you really need "no agent" and just querying services, dig into specific plugins for your applications.

https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/service-monitoring

Comment: the document still says "agent based check". In my use case, we will not have additional agent which will be installed on the remote machine. so, "by_ssh" will not work. It should pure agentless.